# Select object from nested collection using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structure something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<AttributeGroup> AttributeGroups { get; set; }
}

class AttributeGroup
{
    public IEnumerable<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

class Attribute
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all 'Attributes' which has a specific 'SomeProp' value no matter which Attribute Group they belong to.

For example, `SomeProperty== 'A'` can be found in both `MyClassObj.AttributeGroup[0]` and `MyClassObj.AttributeGroup[5]` and I need to write a Linq (or something like that) to fetch two objects from these two different attributegroups.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First select all attributes from all attribute groups, then only select the ones with your property.

```
IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes =
    myClassInstance
        .AttributeGroups
        .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes)
        .Where(x => x.SomeProperty == 'A');
```

Other Linq-style syntax:

```
IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes =
    from attributeGroup in myClassInstance.AttributeGroups
    from attribute in attributeGroup.Attributes
    where attribute.SomeProperty == 'A'
    select attribute;
```

Comment: `group` is a keyword - use `@group` or rename this range variable

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at SelectMany (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).

For example:

```
myClassObjs.SelectMany(o => o.AttributeGroups.SelectMany(g => g.Attributes)).Where(a => a.SomeProp == "A")
```

This line selects all Attribute objects of all AttributeGroups of all MyClass objects where SomeProp equals "A". a in the lambda expression for Where is of type Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't clear; I can't tell what you mean by, "two object from these two different attributegroups". I'll guess that you want the groups that have attributes with the property in question:

```
from g in MyClassObj.AttributeGroups
where g.Any(attr => attr.SomeProperty == "A")
select g
```

Comment: He wants the two attribute-objects that fit the condition, no matter what group they are in. It's actually pretty clear.